# CE certification for toner cartridges of laser printers

Tags: european-union

Concerning toner cartridges and drum units of laser printers, I'm interested in ascertaining
whether, according to European Commission Directives currently in force,
a CE Certification document is produced:

1. by the manufacturer (i.e. self-certified), or
2. only by a Notified Body

The subject seems to be related with the "level of risk" of products,
so a related issue is the established level of risk for cartridges of laser printers.

Concerning the above, I would like some guidance on the online availability of relevant information.

Comment: What does CE stand for? Which directive are you referring to?

Comment: @ohwilleke I guess it is the [CE markings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking)

Comment: @ohwilleke  Yes, as SJuan76 says, I'm interested in the document that supports a CE marking.